# VLC has different styles for Closed Captions vs. Subtitles. How to stylize closed captions in VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Apparently, VLC has different styles for Closed Captions than for Subtitles.

The first attached image shows Closed Captions (embedded in the MKV).
The second snapshot is with Subtitles.

Both snapshots were taken from the same video, same playing session.

Can we change the format of closed captions in VLC? How?

n.b.

- I KNOW HOW TO CUSTOMIZE SUBTITLES.
- the question is only about CLOSED CAPTIONS.

**example ffprobe** containing above mention *Clost Captions*

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'view.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.4 + libmatroska v1.4.5
    creation_time   : 2019-06-12T08:06:14.000000Z
  Duration: 00:36:41.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1133 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 992x558, Closed Captions, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.96 fps, 29.96 tbr, 1k tbn, 96k tbc (default) (forced)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 1036044
      BPS-eng         : 1036044
      DURATION        : 00:36:41.048000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:36:41.048000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 65890
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 65890
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 285047967
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 285047967
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.8.0 ('Kuglblids') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.8.0 ('Kuglblids') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2019-06-12 08:06:14
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-06-12 08:06:14
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
```

**Sample Shots:**

closed captions:

[image]

subtitles:

[image]

Comment: I'm curious about what format these closed captions use, i.e. what `ffprobe` or MKVToolNix report about your .mkv files.

Comment: @grawity added ffprobe stream output in the post. There were 2 streams only: video with optional CC, and an audio stream (not relevant here).